# DateTime Parameter Throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When passing a parameter, sometimes I get the following error thrown

> 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'

dates like this it does not like:

**(Chrome)**

`date=2017-03-28T13%3a01%3a59+01%3a00`

`date=2017-04-01T10%3a35%3a57+01%3a00`

**(Safari 10)**

`date=2017-06-02`

```
public ActionResult Add(string date = null)
{
   DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
   if (date != null)
   {
      startTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why parsing the date yourself when the model-binder can do it for you (using `public ActionResult Add(DateTime? date = null)`)?

Comment: your date looks to be encoded, that is problematic for a `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: You should probably decode the date. Try `DateTime.Parse(Uri.UnescapeDataString(date));`

Comment: Assuming that what you've quoted is the value of `date` in your code then the problem will be that your date is seemingly urlencoded. I would have expected it to be decoded by the time you call Parse on it though. Is that actually the value as it is in the method or is that the value as you ahve copied it from a url?

Comment: @Pikoh could you please provide this as answer - seems valid to me

Comment: I was waiting for OP to clarify if the input dates where encoded, or it was just a typo copying them here. Anyway, i see @BorisSokolov just added it for me, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to unescape the string:

```
public ActionResult Add(string date = null)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (date != null)
    {
        startTime = DateTime.Parse(Uri.UnescapeDataString(date));
    }
}
```